# Ejabberd searchable JID

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd

I'm writing an android app that uses asmack and using Ejabberd as an xmpp server. and it seems that they only way to support search in Ejabberd is that data forms, I've enabled the vcard jvud.mydomain but search won't return jid as a searchable field. do I miss configuration in ejabberd?

Regards,

Ahmad Hamad